# In visual studio, is there a way to step back to see what the few lines executed before were?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In visual studio, is there a way to step back to see what the few lines executed before were?
I hit an unhandled exception in my code, and what I would like to do is step back (without re-executing) so I could see the class/method that called the method that threw the exception.
This is in C#

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack (Ctrl + Alt + C is default bindings (I think))
```

Will show you the history of execution, you can double click events to go to definition, however you cannot step back in code
But you can drag your little yellow arrow to another point in the code to re-execute some code, again this will not change what has already been executed

Comment: Yep, that's what I was doing, going backwards would have been ideal, but as Breckon suggests, it will be in 2010, which will be good!

Comment: as @Stephen Oberauer stated, only available in the Ultimate edition of VS2010 an onwards, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/21/the-future-of-debugging-is-here-visual-studio-2010-now-supports-stepping-back-in-the-debugger.aspx

Comment: Call Stack is not the execution history.

Answer (score 12):

VS2010 is supposed to be able to support historical debugging in which you can go backwards as you suggest. http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2009/05/13/historical-debugging-in-visual-studio-team-system-2010.aspx

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in VS2008.

Comment: This is called "IntelliTrace" and is only available in the Ultimate edition of VS2010.

Comment: for a current MS doc on IntelliTrace see [this answer by shaair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50260341/16049096)

Answer (score 11):

Just you need to drag the little yellow arrow to any different point to re-execute the code you need.

Note: This will not change what has already been executed.

Answer (score 7):

Its too late but hope so it help for new comers. This is the [Step-back while debugging with IntelliTrace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/12/step-back-while-debugging-with-intellitrace/)

Comment: note: IntelliTrace is only available in Visual Studio **Enterprise** edition. [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace-features?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 3):

The latest Visual Studio Preview (as of today: 2017-10-16) has "stepping back"

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

"Improved debugging capabilities such as stepping back"

Answer (score 0):

Because SO keeps showing `The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!`

So I had to give up on revising [sal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50260341/13792395)and a separate answer。

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace-features?view=vs-2022) say:

> IntelliTrace is available in Visual Studio Enterprise edition, but not in the Visual Studio Professional or Community editions.