# Is there any free Windows debugger allowing backwards stepping with C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

By backwards stepping i do not mean the average call stack features. But i refer to what is also called "replay debugging", "reverse debugging", "time-machine debugging","historical debugging" and "Omniscient Debugging".

Since Visual Studio´s IntelliTrace feature not applies to C++.

I am looking for either:

A:
A free C++ debugger, supporting "backwards stepping". That can be either be integrated with visual studio (with an extension or something) or run parallel without any problems.

B:
Some way to give the regular debugger "backwards stepping" capabilities. Via extension or other method.

From what i have understood the Gdb (gnu debugger) now supports this feature. However i have found no windows port (for debugging windows applications) to be free.

I am personally using Visual Studio 2012 , but generalizing this question for any version of visual studio is more than acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In visual studio, is there a way to step back to see what the few lines executed before were?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752591/in-visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-step-back-to-see-what-the-few-lines-executed)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The call stack only stores information for the current call tree. I can go up in the call stack but only down the same way again.

Comment: @DavidJensen: He didn't ask about the call stack. He asked about the same thing you did. The accepted answer says that the call stack is the best you can get.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but further info here: [bidirectional-or-reverse-debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/522619/424459)