# Debugging with VS15 community, history

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am debugging my .dll and it inconsistently crashes (once every 30 minutes or so), when I hook a debugger I receive the error, "Frame not in module". So my question is, is it possible to view the last line of code execute from my program, if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Open the call stack window.

Comment: @Jake Reid, I add an answer, any update? Is it helpful for you? Please feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree with Retired's suggestion, you could use the call stack windows where you can drag a yellow arrow to another point in the code to re-execute some code.

Reference:

[In visual studio, is there a way to step back to see what the few lines executed before were?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752591/in-visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-step-back-to-see-what-the-few-lines-executed).

In addition, like this old blog here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/10/21/the-future-of-debugging-is-here-visual-studio-2010-now-supports-stepping-back-in-the-debugger/

I also test it in my VS2015 Enterprise version, you could use the IntelliTrace function like A, and then re-view the last line of code execute during debugging time.

[image]